Autolisp & JavaScript convert Lat/Long to X(Easting) Y(Northing)
I'm wanting to create a BricsCAD script which takes Lat/Long WGS84 and converts it into the BNG Easting/Northing
Similar to Grid Reference Finder, Webapps BGS Converter & Google Earth's long/lat but I'm wanting to avoid using an API to allow it to work offline.
I've found a few forums which provide have similar formulas in JavaScript but when I've tested them it's always returning the incorrect values as to what the above suggest converters use or doesn't match up to Google Earth,
function LLtoNE(lat, lon)
{
  var deg2rad = Math.PI / 180;
  var phi = lat * deg2rad;          // convert latitude to radians
  var lam = lon * deg2rad;          // convert longitude to radians

  a = 6378137.0;                    // WGS84 semi-major axis
  b = 6356752.314245;               // WGS84 semi-minor axis
  e0 = 400000;                      // OSGB easting of false origin
  n0 = -100000;                     // OSGB northing of false origin
  f0 = 0.9996012717;                // OSGB scale factor on central meridian
  e2 = 0.006694380023;              // WGS84 eccentricity squared
  lam0 = -0.034906585039886591;     // OSGB false east
  phi0 = 0.85521133347722145;       // OSGB false north


  var af0 = a * f0;
  var bf0 = b * f0;

  // easting
  var slat2 = Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(phi);
  var nu = af0 / (Math.sqrt(1 - (e2 * (slat2))));
  var rho = (nu * (1 - e2)) / (1 - (e2 * slat2));
  var eta2 = (nu / rho) - 1;
  var p = lam - lam0;
  var IV = nu * Math.cos(phi);
  var clat3 = Math.pow(Math.cos(phi),3);
  var tlat2 = Math.tan(phi) * Math.tan(phi);
  var V = (nu / 6) * clat3 * ((nu / rho) - tlat2);
  var clat5 = Math.pow(Math.cos(phi), 5);
  var tlat4 = Math.pow(Math.tan(phi), 4);
  var VI = (nu / 120) * clat5 * ((5 - (18 * tlat2)) + tlat4 + (14 * eta2) - (58 * tlat2 * eta2));
  east = e0 + (p * IV) + (Math.pow(p, 3) * V) + (Math.pow(p, 5) * VI);

  // northing
  var n = (af0 - bf0) / (af0 + bf0);
  var M = Marc(bf0, n, phi0, phi);
  var I = M + (n0);
  var II = (nu / 2) * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(phi);
  var III = ((nu / 24) * Math.sin(phi) * Math.pow(Math.cos(phi), 3)) * (5 - Math.pow(Math.tan(phi), 2) + (9 * eta2));
  var IIIA = ((nu / 720) * Math.sin(phi) * clat5) * (61 - (58 * tlat2) + tlat4);
  north = I + ((p * p) * II) + (Math.pow(p, 4) * III) + (Math.pow(p, 6) * IIIA);

  console.log(east)
  console.log(north)
}

function Marc(bf0, n, phi0, phi)
{
  var Marc = bf0 * (((1 + n + ((5 / 4) * (n * n)) + ((5 / 4) * (n * n * n))) * (phi - phi0))
   - (((3 * n) + (3 * (n * n)) + ((21 / 8) * (n * n * n))) * (Math.sin(phi - phi0)) * (Math.cos(phi + phi0)))
   + ((((15 / 8) * (n * n)) + ((15 / 8) * (n * n * n))) * (Math.sin(2 * (phi - phi0))) * (Math.cos(2 * (phi + phi0))))
   - (((35 / 24) * (n * n * n)) * (Math.sin(3 * (phi - phi0))) * (Math.cos(3 * (phi + phi0)))));
  return(Marc);
}

I want 50.7876108 , -1.0978817 to return 463688 , 099059 but instead im getting 463589, 099139
Could anyone point me in the right direction, or explain where I'm going wrong?

Try using a library like: https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js?
